# How do I install phantomjs-prebuilt on my AWS instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, pdf, amazon-ec2

I've been trying to install Node module "html-pdf" on my AWS EC2 instance

npm install html-pdf

[while installing html-pdf module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMzKN.png)

In above image some dependencies is skipping which is important for html-pdf module. whenever I restart my node app It keep showing errors in my logs that No phantomjs-prebuilt module found and when I try to install phantomjs-prebuilt module it keep showing me this error

npm install phantomjs-prebuilt

[error while installing phantomjs-prebuilt module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnqpV.png)

AWS keep blocking this module. Everything working fine on my local machine

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Yes I have found the solution .. 
sudo npm install -g phantomjs@2.1.1 --unsafe-perm, 
npm config set unsafe-perm=true **Use these commands for installation**